# Check if dataset is already open with SASFILE

Tags: sas

I have a program that opens two files with `SASFILE` statement. You can see what SASFILE can do on [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001500739.htm).

If I don't unload SAS datasets with `sasfile close` statement before trying to open them again, lets say by rerunning code in the same session, it causes an error.

Is there a way I could check that the dataset is already loaded and then conditionally unload/load/do_nothing?

Comment: I've been researching this, but can't find anything definitive that won't specifically cause an error. In the past, I've just made it a habit to throw `sasfile close` onto before loading it, even though it will spit out an error.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a macro that remembers you did open it.

```
%macro sasFileOpen(lib, mem);
    %global &lib._&mem._open;
    %if &&&lib._&mem._open NE open %then %do;
        sasfile &lib..&mem..data open; 
        %let &lib._&mem._open = open;
    %end;
%mend;
```

Then use it this way:

```
libname mydata 'SAS-library';

%sasFileOpen (mydata, census);  

data test; 
   set mydata.census;  
run;

%sasFileOpen (mydata, census);  

data test; 
   set mydata.census;  
run;

proc summary data=mydata.census print;  
run;

data mydata.census;  
   modify mydata.census; 
   .
   . (statements to modify data)
   .
run;

sasfile mydata.census close;
```

Sorry for not testing it, my SAS installation is currently corrupted.